# How to avoid duplicate record processing in multiple instance batch scripts

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing

we are trying to create a batch script which reads millions of records and try to process them, Since the processing take longer time (e.g : more 6 hrs) we are planning to run multiple instances of batch scripts.
How to avoid multiple instances picking the same record for processing?

We tried the below approach

> pre-assigning instances with range of records using a manager .(i.e, let say 3 instances and 6 million records, each instance will get 2 million record).

> stamping the instance_id in each record after reading. Instances always picks the records which have null value in instance_id

Is there any other way to avoid duplicate record processing.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Spring Batch, you have several options to scale your job. Here is a non-exhaustive list of options:

- Create a job with a multi-threaded step: each thread will process a distinct chunk of data
- Create a job with a partitioned step: each worker step is assigned a distinct partition (workers could be local threads or remote JVMs)
- Create different job instances where each job instance is assigned a distinct partition

Please refer to the [Scaling and Parallel Processing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/scalability.html#scalability) section from the documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively we can use DB Partitioning strategies to fix the duplicates record processing

1. Fixed and Even Break-Up of Record Set
2. Break up by a Key Column
3. Breakup by Views
4. Addition of a Processing Indicator
5. Extract Table to a Flat File
6. Use of a Hashing Column

[Spring Document reference - click here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/spring-batch-intro.html#batchProcessingStrategy)